# Use a parent window to query closed status of opened child windows

Tags: javascript

I have coded the two HTML pages below.
Page2d.php is intended to display a select element that allows the client to select an ID, then open a new window with that ID showing on a new page (Page3b.php) when the button is clicked. The parent (Page2d.php) keeps an array of child windows globally.

Problem 1: ID number selected did not write to child window.
Because the script is malfunctioning I receive an error in the Google console stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

I am using an array of IDs to record those selected and I realize this might not be the best idea but I tried so many different ways with no success. Help !!!!

### Page2d.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
       <title>Page 2d</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var IDS = [];
    var WindowTabs = 0;
    var WindowRef = [];

    function TestIfOpen() {
        var OkToOpen = 1; //true

        //Get the ID selected
        var sel = document.getElementById('_ID');
        var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
        var IDselected = opt.value;

        if (WindowRef.length == 0) {
            IDS[WindowTabs] = IDselected;
            WindowRef[WindowTabs] = window.open('Page3b.php?TAB=' + WindowTabs, '');
            WindowRef[WindowTabs].document.getElementById('_ID').innerHTML = "ID equals " + IDselected;
        } else {
            for (var x = 0; x < WindowRef.length; x++) {
                if(!WindowRef[x].closed) {
                    if(IDS[x] == IDselected) {
                        OkToOpen = 0; //false
                        alert("A window for this ID is already opened");
                    }
                } else {
                    IDS[x] = 0;
                }
            }
            if (OkToOpen == 1) {
                WindowTabs++;
                IDS[WindowTabs] = IDselected;
                WindowRef[WindowTabs] = window.open('Page3b.php?TAB=' + WindowTabs, '');
                WindowRef[WindowTabs].document.getElementById('_ID').innerHTML = "ID equals " + IDselected;
            }
        }
    }
</script>



</head>
<body>

<?php
    echo "<form method='POST' action='$PHP_SELF'>";
    $IDS = array("200","201","202","203","204","205","206");
    echo "Select an ID:<p><select name='_ID' id='_ID'>";
    foreach($IDS as $value) {
        echo "<option value='".$value."'";
        if($value == $_POST['_ID']) {
            echo " selected ";
        }
        echo ">".$value."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></p>";
    echo "<button type='button' onclick='TestIfOpen();'>Click Here to Open a window for this ID</button></form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Page3b.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
       <title>Page 3b</title>
</head>
<body>
<span id='_ID'>This is original text</span><br>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S.
My original post contained errors in array management that I discovered and have repaired in the code above.

Comment: Use a load event before trying to access elements in new window

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Could you help with an example?

Comment: Try `WindowRef[WindowTabs].onload = function(){ /* find element*/}`

Comment: Thank you very much. Your idea worked.

Comment: WindowRef[WindowTabs].onload = function(){ WindowRef[WindowTabs].document.getElementById('_ID').innerHTML = "ID = " + IDselected;}